# Setting height for Bokeh Tabs

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Is it possible to manually set a fixed height for every tabs of bokeh ? The code below generates two Tabs but in the HTML file, their height are based on the biggest one.

I would like to have a HTML file of two Tabs with a fixed height, and Tabs which exceed the fixed height would be managed by vertical scroll bar.

Thanks for help

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("slider.html")

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=3000) # the biggest height, setting height for all tabs
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ], height=300) # this height is not considered in the HTML

show(tabs)
```

Comment: Please check if `Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ], width=300, height=300, height_policy="fit", sizing_mode="fixed")` solves your problem.

Comment: @mosc9575 with this code, the scrolling bar is still the same for both tabs, which is set up for the 3000 height, so there is a white empty space under the first chart of the first tabs